# How to check an image dimensions using js or node

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a `sample.jpg` file and I want to check its dimensions.

The desired logic goes like this:

```
var img = require('./sample.jpg');
console.log(typeof img) // returns string -> Image
console.log(img.height) // returns number -> 300
console.log(img.width)  // returns nubmer -> 250
```

Never mind the return of the `typeof`. I just wan't to get the dimensions. But that is the simple break down of what where I am going. Is there a way to do this using node or plain js?

Comment: There seems to be a popular [node package to do that](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-size)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `image-size` npm module:

```
npm install image-size --save
```

Then can get dimentions like this:

```
var sizeOf = require('image-size');
var dimensions = sizeOf('./sample.jpg');
console.log(dimensions.width, dimensions.height);
```

For more information go through `image-size` [documentations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-size)

Comment: You are a savage sir! Thank you very much!

Comment: I got error cannot resolve `fs`

Comment: @Marfin.F, Are you using the fs library? it's difficult to help you based on your error without seeing your code.

Comment: guys, just make sure you are importing this in getServerSideProps

Answer (score 6):

You can use [**GraphicsMagick**](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) or [**ImageMagick**](https://imagemagick.org/index.php). I recommend GraphicsMagick as it's lot faster.

Install the npm package [**gm**](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) and use like this:

```js
gm = require('gm');

// obtain the size of an image
gm('test.jpg')
.size(function (err, size) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('width = ' + size.width);
    console.log('height = ' + size.height);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jpeg-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpeg-js).

From their docs:

```
var jpeg = require('jpeg-js');
var jpegData = fs.readFileSync('grumpycat.jpg');
var rawImageData = jpeg.decode(jpegData);
console.log(rawImageData);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use this using JS (only works in browser)

```
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = './sample.jpg';
 console.log(img.height);
 console.log(img.width);
```

For node, you can install **canvas** library.

Comment: yes I tried that, it gave me this error: ReferenceError: Image is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\marvenwilsons\Desktop\h\id.js:1286:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3