# How to get image width/height in next.js?

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

In my app I allow users to upload their images. Upon uploading it goes into public folder, and in database there is only a direct link for future requests.

When displaying these images on the page I encounter a problem. `Image` component wants to know height and width of each image. And so I want to know it too.

What are the available options for the workflow in this situation? Both processing while uploading and while requesting will work for me.

Comment: Have you considered using [`layout="fill"`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#layout) rather than providing dimensions?

Comment: @juliomalves I tried it, but it seems like too much trouble to work properly. With the same result and far less amount of effort I can use image component from SemanticUI library, which I use in my project. As of now, I consider `Image` to do more harm than good.

Comment: @juliomalves  **layout="fill"** hass been depreciated

Comment: @juliomalves has it?  Its in the docs to use it for responsive layouts

Answer (score 1):

You can use image-size npm module:

```
npm install image-size --save
```

then:

```
var sizeOf = require('image-size');
var dimensions = sizeOf('./sample.jpg');
console.log(dimensions.width, dimensions.height);
```

from: [How to check an image dimensions using js or node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46716730/how-to-check-an-image-dimensions-using-js-or-node/46716800)

Comment: `image-size` depends on `fs`. It doesn't work if you run Next.js on edge runtime.